# Copy mutable data structure and preserve sharing?

Tags: ocaml

Suppose that I have a `int ref list` and I want to make a copy of it. One option is the following:

```ml
let copy_ref_list : int ref list -> int ref list =
  List.map (fun x -> ref !x)
```

However, this losing sharing within the nodes. For example,

```ml
let v =
  let x = ref 0 in
  copy_ref_list [x; x; x] (* creates three copies of [x] *)
```

Is there an efficient way to implement a function that would produce only one copy of `x` above, so that the result is the same as:

```ml
let copy_of_v =
  let x = ref 0 in
  [x; x; x]
```

It seems like I can use a memoized copy function with a `Hashtbl`, but does that give the right behavior on references?

```ml
let copy_ref_list (x : int ref list) : int ref list =
  let memo = Hashtbl.create 17 in
  let copy x =
    try Hashtbl.find memo x
    with Not_found ->
      let y = ref !x in
      let () = Hashtbl.add memo x y in
      y
  in
  List.map copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a ref containing a single mutable value as shown, it isn't possible to use a Hashtbl to optimize the preservation of sharing. You can't hash the address of a value because GC may change that address.

So in this case a (less performant) scan must be used to preserve sharing. The following example uses a list of pairs, `(r1, r2)`, where r1 is the original ref in the list and r2 is the new ref. This `updates` list is scanned using `List.find_opt` to find r1 refs that occur more than once in the original list, and use the corresponding r2 in the new list.

```ml
let copy_ref_list (ls : int ref list) : int ref list =
  let rec copy updates = function
    | [] -> []
    | r :: rs -> (
      match List.find_opt (fun (r1, _) -> r == r1) updates with
      | Some (_, r2) -> r2 :: copy updates rs
      | None ->
          let r2 = ref !r in
          let updates' = (r, r2) :: updates in
          r2 :: copy updates' rs )
  in
  copy [] ls
```

Another approach is to define the mutable value as a field in a record along with a unique id field, and use a Hashtbl with a hash on the unique id. A ref would not be used in this case. For example:

```ml
type 'a val_with_id = {mutable value: 'a; unique_id: int}

let copy_val_with_id_list (ls : 'a val_with_id list) : 'a val_with_id list = ...
```

This is a more intrusive solution since it requires maintaining this record and assigning a unique id each time a value is created. It also uses more memory. However, it may provide better copying performance for large lists since a hash lookup is used instead of a list scan per copied element.

For details on creating such a Hashtbl and maintaining a unique id see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290155/2607027

Here is a minimal example of using a Hashtbl and val_with_id, using code roughly similar to the code posted in the question.

```ml
let next_id =
  let id_sequence = ref (-1) in
  fun () -> incr id_sequence ; !id_sequence

type 'a val_with_id = {mutable value: 'a; unique_id: int}

let with_id v = {value= v; unique_id= next_id ()}

let copy_val_with_id_list (ls : 'a val_with_id list) : 'a val_with_id list =
  let memo = Hashtbl.create 17 in
  let copy r =
    try Hashtbl.find memo r.unique_id with
    | Not_found ->
        let r' = with_id r.value in
        Hashtbl.add memo r.unique_id r' ;
        r'
  in
  List.map copy ls
```

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. I have corrected the description of the alternative solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your `copy_ref_list` function fails to copy the sharing structure. It doesn't check for sharing but only whether the referenced values are equal. The built-in comparison function for `Hashtbl` is based on `=`, and two references are equal if their contents are equal. Hence the copy will in general have *too much* sharing (rather than not enough).

(Also the last line of your function should read `List.map copy x`.)

Here's an example of the failure:

```
# let wlist = [ref 3; ref 3];;
val wlist : int ref list = [{contents = 3}; {contents = 3}]
# let wlist_copy = copy_ref_list wlist;;
val wlist_copy : int ref list = [{contents = 3}; {contents = 3}]
# List.hd wlist_copy := 4;;
- : unit = ()
# wlist_copy;;
- : int ref list = [{contents = 4}; {contents = 4}]
```

As you can see, the copy of wlist has shared values even though they aren't shared in the original list:

```
# List.hd wlist := 5;;
- : unit = ()
# wlist;;
- : int ref list = [{contents = 5}; {contents = 3}]
```

I think it will work if you use the functorial interface to `Hashtbl` and base your equality test on physical equality `==`. The behavior of `==` when applied to mutable values behaves as you would expect, i.e., it will detect sharing.